# how to Parse string to DateTime with string number

Tags: c#, datetime

I have method like below to convert datetime to string:

```
private string GetCurrentDate(DateTime time)
{
    time = time.AddSeconds(1);
    return $"{time.Year}{time.Month:00}{time.Day}{time.Hour}{time.Minute}{time.Second:00}".Substring(2); 
}
```

the result of Above code is like this :

> 170902145914

now I want to convert that string to datetime , Iused below code , but it throw exception :

```
DateTime seed = DateTime.ParseExact($"{20}170902145914","YYYYmmddHHmmss",CultureInfo.CurrentCulture);
```

how can I do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Case matters, lower case for year, upper case M is month, lower case m is minute. upper case H is 24hour hour format.

```
DateTime seed = DateTime.ParseExact($"20170902145914", "yyyyMMddHHmmss", System.Globalization.CultureInfo.CurrentCulture);
```

Check the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/base-types/custom-date-and-time-format-strings) for more